# Issue with using custom JSON Marshal() for Embedded Structs

Tags: json, struct, go

I am attempting to define a custom JSON marshaler to display some time information in specific formats. Ideally, I'd like to have a struct that stores created/modified values and then embed them into structs that need to keep track of that information. In addition, I want to define a custom date format in the JSON marshaler to use from a client-side application.

I currently have two structs

```
type Timestamp struct {
    Created time.Time
    Modified time.Time
}

type Company struct {
    Id string
    Name string
    Timestamp    
}
```

I want to embed the Timestamp struct into objects that will need to record when items are updated/created. Nothing insane there.

My issues comes when I define

```
func (t Timestamp) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(struct {
        CreatedFormatted string
    }{
        CreatedFormatted: t.Created.Format("Monday Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"),
    })
}
```

When I go to marshal `Company`, I only see the json for the Timestamp but nothing for the Company. I would have thought that the contents of the Company struct **and** the Timestamp struct would have been displayed. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a type embedded in a struct provides a method, that method becomes a part of the embedding struct. Since `Company` embeds `Timestamp`, `Timestamp`'s `MarshalJSON` is available for `Company` as well. When json is looking to marshal a `Company` it sees that it has a `MarshalJSON` method and calls it — and the method it finds only marshals the timestamp field. The default behavior of structs (to marshal each field into its own key in a JSON object) is overridden.

What you can do:

1. Don't use struct embedding, just make `Timestamp` a regular field (even if you declare it as `Timestamp Timestamp`). Then `Company` won't inherit its methods and JSON will work as expected (but other parts of your code that expect embedding might change). Or:
2. Give `Company` its own `MarshalJSON` method that marshalls all of the fields including the timestamp. You could do this by
   a. Copying the fields into a different type that is identical to `Company` but without the embedding, and marshalling that.
   b. Copying the fields into a map and marshalling that.
   c. Marshalling each of the fields independently and string-pasting `fmt.Sprintf({"key1":%s,"key2":%s,...}, m1, m2, ...)` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

By embedding `Timestamp` in `Company` you not only shared member variables, but also the methods. This means you provided `Company.MarshalJSON` method, which is then used by `json` package for marshalling the whole structure. In order to see all the fields you would need to implement an explicit marshaler for `Company` structure as well.

If you only want to format the timestamp in a specific way, the other solution would be to provide your own `time.Time` and providing JSON marshaller there.

For example:

```
type AccessTime time.Time

func (t AccessTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(time.Time(t).Format("Monday Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"))
}

type Timestamp struct {
    Created  AccessTime
    Modified AccessTime
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PhZXPauSyz